# Не работает объединение таблиц через JOIN!

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

Имеется 2 таблицы: в первой есть города с наименованиями, а во второй идентификаторы этих городов. Почему после добавления JOIN выборка с БД перестает работать? Что я делаю здесь неправильно? Без использования JOIN выборка работает прекрасно, но с использованием, ничего не отображает.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class bh_programsModelWorldrating extends JModelList {

  protected function getListQuery()
    {
        $query = parent::getListQuery();

    $query->select($this->getState('a','id, name, worldrating, city_id'));

    $query->from('#__bh_program_schools AS ps');
    $query->where('worldrating_rank > 0');

    $query->select('pc.name AS city_name');
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__bh_program_cities AS pc ON pc.id = ps.city_id');


    return $query;

  }
}
```

Comment: в `select` поправьте `pc.name` на `ps.name`

Comment: @ Dan the Hat, Так я беру название города из таблицы pc (program_cities). Поменял, но ничего не дало

Comment: а, пардон, чего-то я протупил

Comment: @ Dan the Hat, разобрался уже)